# identify patterns in medication use

Tags: logic, stata

This is mostly a logic question.

I am trying to figure out medication taking patterns in a cohort of people. My first step was to find people who are “continuous users” of 4 medicines. I defined continuous use as repeat prescriptions of 4 meds after the 4th drug was initially prescribed.

For some people, they might be a continuous user of 4 meds after initiating their fourth med. I find the 4th drug (4th drugs of interest to me are B, Q, S and T), and then I look to see if this person continually takes 4 drugs in the pattern A+C+D+4th drug. This is how I do this for 4 drugs (mini-dataset is below, labelled 4 drug users);

```
bys id: gen interest=0  
by id: replace interest =1 if  (agent_type == "T" | agent_type =="Q" | agent_type =="S" | agent_type =="B") ///
    &  con_4_4 ==1 & count==4
by id: egen interest4=max(interest)   //notes: this variable tells me if the person has a 4th drug of interest to me; drug B, Q, S or T
    
gen acd_4_1=0
by id: replace acd_4_1 =1 if  (agent_type == "A"| agent_type =="C" | agent_type=="D") & count==1

gen acd_4_2=0
by id: replace acd_4_2 =1 if  (agent_type == "A"| agent_type =="C" | agent_type=="D") & count==2

gen acd_4_3=0
by id: replace acd_4_3 =1 if  (agent_type == "A"| agent_type =="C" | agent_type=="D") & count==3

 by id: egen acd_4_11 =max(acd_4_1)
 by id: egen acd_4_22 =max(acd_4_2)
 by id: egen acd_4_33 =max(acd_4_3)
 
 gen acd_4=1 if acd_4_11 ==1 & acd_4_22 ==1 & acd_4_33 ==1 & interest4==1  //acd_4 is a variable indicating whether people had the desired pattern after initiating their 4th agent

*notes: 
*kate has acd_4 = . because she used a prohibited drug "Q" and also her 4th drug was not of interest to us (was "A" as opposed to T, Q, S or B)
*mark has acd_4==1 because he used the correct pattern A+C+D after the prescription of his 4th drug which was S (count=4, date 5th October 2000)
```

Now, its gets trickier. Other people, who may be switching meds, or discontinuing may not have continuous use of 4 meds until after their 5th med or 6th med. For example, only after the 5th med do they have repeat prescriptions of A+C+D and med 5 which in this case is our drug of interest (again, it will be B, Q, S or T).

If they have another drug B, Q, S, T in addition to their drug of interest and the pattern of interest– then I want to flag this, as I want to exclude that person’s pattern from further consideration. For example, I want med5+A+C+D and not med5+A+C+D+S.

I have figured out a way to do this (mini dataset below, labelled as "5drug users"), but my code is clunky and will take a very long time on my big dataset. Can anyone make some suggestions to 1) improve my logic or 2) improve my coding, or 3) both!

```
gen interest5=0
 bys id: replace interest5 =1 if  (agent_type == "T" | agent_type =="Q" | agent_type =="S" | agent_type =="B") ///
    & con_5_5 ==1 & count==5
 by id: egen interest55 = max(interest5)
 drop interest5
 ren interest55 interest5
    
    
by id: gen A5=1 if (agent_type =="A") & (rx_date >fifth_con_full & rx_date <=fifth_con_full+180) & interest5==1
by id: egen AA55=max(A5)
drop A5
 
by id: gen C5=1 if (agent_type =="C") & (rx_date >fifth_con_full & rx_date <=fifth_con_full+180) & interest5==1
by id: egen C55=max(C5)
drop C5

by id: gen D5=1 if (agent_type =="D") & (rx_date >fifth_con_full & rx_date <=fifth_con_full+180) & interest5==1
by id: egen D55=max(D5)
drop D5

by id: gen acd_5=1 if (AA55==1 & C55==1 & D55==1) & interest5==1

*make sure patient isn't taking any of the other comparator agents
 by id: gen prohib=1 if (agent_type == "T" | agent_type =="Q" | agent_type =="S" | agent_type =="B") ///
        & (rx_date >fifth_con_full & rx_date <=fifth_con_full+180) & interest5==1 & count!=5        //here the count!=5 code indicates that I want stata to flag if the patient is taking any of the comparator agents, not inclusive ofthe compartor agent of interest, in this case the comparator agent is count==5
by id: egen prohib55=max(prohib)

by id: gen pattern=1 if acd_5 ==1 & prohib55 !=1

*notes: 
*mary has pattern = . because she used a prohibited drug "B" after the prescription of her 4th agent (here count=5, agent_type "T", starting on 29th July 05) 
*Pat has pattern=1 because he used A+C+D after his 4th agent (here count=5, agent-type==B, starting on 28th Jan 09)
*Sue has pattern=. because she used a prohibited drug "T" after the precription of her 4th agent (here count=5, agenttype==B, startig on 25th Feb 2011)
```

**Datasets**

### 4drug users

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 id int rx_date str1 agent_type byte count int fourth_full byte con_4_4 int fourth_con_full
"kate" 16728 "Q" 1     . 1 16733
"kate" 16728 "C" 3     . 1 16733
"kate" 16733 "A" 4 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16758 "B" 2 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16758 "Q" 1 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16758 "C" 3 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16762 "A" 4 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16784 "C" 3 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16784 "A" 4 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16784 "Q" 1 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16784 "B" 2 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16812 "Q" 1 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16812 "B" 2 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16812 "A" 4 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16812 "C" 3 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16841 "Q" 1 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16841 "C" 3 16733 1 16733
"kate" 16841 "B" 2 16733 1 16733
"mark" 14874 "C" 2     . 1 14888
"mark" 14874 "A" 1     . 1 14888
"mark" 14888 "S" 4 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14888 "D" 3 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14930 "S" 4 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14930 "C" 2 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14930 "A" 1 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14930 "D" 3 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14965 "S" 4 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14965 "A" 1 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14965 "D" 3 14888 1 14888
"mark" 14965 "C" 2 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15028 "S" 4 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15028 "C" 2 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15028 "A" 1 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15028 "D" 3 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15097 "C" 2 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15097 "A" 1 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15097 "D" 3 14888 1 14888
"mark" 15097 "S" 4 14888 1 14888
end
format %tddd-Mon-YY rx_date
format %tddd-Mon-YY fourth_full
format %tddd-Mon-YY fourth_con_full
```

### 5drug users

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 id int rx_date str1 agent_type byte count int fifth_full byte con_5_5 int fifth_con_full
"pat"  17910 "D" 1     . 1 17925
"pat"  17910 "A" 4     . 1 17925
"pat"  17910 "C" 2     . 1 17925
"pat"  17925 "B" 5 17925 1 17925
"pat"  17948 "B" 5 17925 1 17925
"pat"  17969 "C" 2 17925 1 17925
"pat"  17969 "B" 5 17925 1 17925
"pat"  17969 "D" 1 17925 1 17925
"pat"  17969 "A" 4 17925 1 17925
"pat"  18028 "D" 1 17925 1 17925
"pat"  18028 "B" 5 17925 1 17925
"pat"  18028 "C" 2 17925 1 17925
"pat"  18028 "A" 4 17925 1 17925
"pat"  18081 "D" 1 17925 1 17925
"pat"  18081 "C" 2 17925 1 17925
"mary" 16618 "C" 2     . 1 16646
"mary" 16618 "D" 3     . 1 16646
"mary" 16618 "B" 1     . 1 16646
"mary" 16646 "T" 5 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16679 "A" 4 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16679 "C" 2 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16679 "D" 3 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16679 "B" 1 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16681 "T" 5 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16737 "D" 3 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16737 "B" 1 16646 1 16646
"mary" 16737 "A" 4 16646 1 16646
"sue"  18676 "D" 3     . 1 18683
"sue"  18676 "C" 2     . 1 18683
"sue"  18676 "T" 4     . 1 18683
"sue"  18683 "B" 5 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18729 "C" 2 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18729 "B" 5 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18729 "T" 4 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18729 "D" 3 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18730 "C" 2 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18779 "C" 2 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18779 "T" 4 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18779 "D" 3 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18826 "A" 1 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18834 "C" 2 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18834 "T" 4 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18834 "D" 3 18683 1 18683
"sue"  18889 "D" 3 18683 1 18683
end
format %tddd-Mon-YY rx_date
format %tddd-Mon-YY fifth_full
format %tddd-Mon-YY fifth_con_full
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but it won't fit well into a comment. Your code is clear but can be condensed. For example, the first block can be simplified to

```
gen interest = inlist(agent_type, "T", "Q", "S", "B") &  con_4_4 ==1 & count==4
bysort id: egen interest4 = max(interest)     

gen acd_4_1 = inlist(agent_type, "A", "C", "D") & count==1
gen acd_4_2 = inlist(agent_type, "A", "C", "D") & count==2
gen acd_4_3 = inlist(agent_type, "A", "C", "D") & count==3

by id: egen acd_4_11 = max(acd_4_1)
by id: egen acd_4_22 = max(acd_4_2)
by id: egen acd_4_33 = max(acd_4_3)

gen acd_4= 1 if acd_4_11 ==1 & acd_4_22 ==1 & acd_4_33 ==1 & interest4==1
```

That's 13 lines down to 9.

Just cosmetic, but above all you want your real question to be clear and to be answered.

The small techniques there include

1. Omitting `by:` when it makes no difference to the outcome.
2. Boiling a `generate` and `replace` pair to produce 0, 1 variables into a single statement.
3. Using `inlist()` to catch alternatives concisely.

Rewriting the question more briefly will make attempts at your real question more likely.

Comment: thank you for comment, and shortened code; I've learned now from that. I fully accept your comment on keeping the question brief, and I'll try to reduce, but was keen to fully explain where I'm coming from and feared omitting something crucial to help readers understand.